# É possível "simular" Templates do C++ em C?

Tags: c, c++, template

Tomando uma estrutura de dados do tipo pilha com *array* **por exemplo**:

```
typedef struct stack_s {
    int top;
    int item[STACK_MAX_SIZE];
} stack_t;
```

A dúvida aparece quando por algum motivo desejo utilizar uma pilha com outro tipo de dado que não seja `int`, devo modificar o código da pilha? Devo criar outra pilha? Essas alternativas não me parecem muito boas. Mas em C++ existem os *templates* que surgem para resolver problemas nesse mesmo contexto. Então é possível de alguma forma simular os *templates* do C++ em C?

Comment: Dá pra fazer alguma coisa com macros, mas fica nojento. Acredito que a biblioteca GObject foi nessa direção, você pode analisar as soluções que eles adotaram para implementar um framework com OOP e tudo em C puro. Mas nunca gostei de GObject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não exatamente.

Até pode criar uma ferramenta para ler o código genérico e gerar os concretos para cada tipo. É difícil, trabalhoso, fácil fazer errado, e provavelmente não compensa.

Sempre é possível tentar algo criativo com macro, ma será bem ruim.

Se estiver usando C11 tem a macro [`_Generic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic). Não acho que fica bom. E não é algo que costuma ser usado, na verdade nunca vi um código usando, até porque nem todos compiladores suportam.

A ideia é que se precisa disto use C++ e seja feliz.

Uma prática que se costuma usar em casos assim é polimorfismo, mas perde a segurança de tipo e há uma pequena perda de performance.

Em vez de usar um tipo específico usa-se `void *`, desta forma o tipo fica genérico, o que for usado será aceito. Em compensação pode mandar qualquer coisa que aceita, a não ser que crie uma lógica tentando impedir o erro, o que não é simples de fazer certo em C. Em geral o costume é confiar que o programador usará certo.

C é uma linguagem com tipagem fraca com baixa segurança de tipo. Um dos motivos para a criação do C++ é justamente resolver esse problema.

Tem um [exemplo básico](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/139229-generic-polymorphic-stack-implementation-plain-c.html).