# Como implementar de forma correta o polimorfismo?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, polimorfismo

Uma das primeiras coisas que ouvimos falar quando estudamos o paradigma de orientação a objetos é o polimorfismo mas como podemos ou "devemos" implementar o mesmo, já que se trata de um conceito vemos várias formas de implementação, como posso entender melhor a forma de implementação e quando utilizá-la?

Comment: Sugiro conferir os bons casos de uso de polimorfismo no mundo real, por exemplo as hierarquias de Views em frameworks de UI. Orientação a objetos (e polimorfismo junto com ela) são muito hypeados, frameworks vencedores como o do iOS (Cocoa Touch) são notoriamente "horizontais", ou seja, não têm profundas hierarquias de classes, nem usam polimorfismo para tudão, então é legal procurar também pelas situações onde ele não cabe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Questão errada

Está pensando na questão errada. O certo é pensar em um problema e procurar as ferramentas corretas para resolvê-lo da melhor forma. Uma dessas ferramentas é polimorfismo. E existem mecanismos diferentes para atender esta demanda, cada linguagem implementa de um jeito (ou de mais de um).

O mais importante é não fazer polimorfismo onde não precisa dele. Na verdade não fazer orientação a objeto onde não precisa desta orientação (que pode ser **chamado de [paradigma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101), embora [há dúvidas se é mesmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108047/101)**). As pessoas tendem a se apegar à ferramentas e querem usá-las de qualquer jeito. É mais ou menos como comprar um maçarico culinário e querer usar para coisas que não são creme *brolè* (ok, serve para algumas outras coisas, mas poucas, não para sair queimando qualquer coisa).

Então entenda o polimorfismo e o aplique quando precisar.

## O que é o polimorfismo

Uma definição do polimorfismo é a capacidade de algo ser executado de acordo com o estado (ou o seu tipo) em determinado momento. Use quando precisa disto. Então é a capacidade de assumir várias formas.

Uma outra forma de defini-lo é ele ser uma [substituição de um condicional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4731/101) ([geralmente `if` ou `switch`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135702/101)) para decidir qual o comportamento ou estado deve usar em determinado momento. Esse é um dos motivos que se diz que é melhor [programar para interfaces](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73633/101).

O polimorfismo pode ser resolvido em tempo de compilação ou de execução, dependendo do mecanismo usado e da necessidade.

## Mecanismo

Em geral você implementa um problema e usa o polimorfismo como mecanismo, por isso não dá para dizer como implementá-lo. A não ser que esteja querendo implementar o mecanismo. Mas quase ninguém quer, geralmente isto só é necessário de você estiver criando uma linguagem. Tem uma [pergunta que mostra um pouco isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53108/101).

Mesmo que esteja falando do uso do mecanismo [depende da linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/213951/101), não tem como responder genericamente.

[Outro mecanismo muito usado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131890/101), mas pode ser [implementado de várias maneiras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159048/101). E tem uma forma que é uma [especialização do polimorfismo, mas damos outro nome](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137185/101). É possível existir outros, mas esses são os mais usados e documentados, então as 3 formas apresentadas são as mais corretas para os casos gerais.

## Onde aprender e ver exemplos

Podemos mostrar o que é para entender e depois aplicar quando necessário. Eu e outras pessoas já respondemos sobre isto. Se ainda tiver dúvidas específicas pode abrir novas perguntas sobre o que faltou. Acho que a [melhor resposta seria essa minha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153042/101).

Há uma [pergunta com diversos *links* para outras respostas sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154421/101).

E finalmente um [exemplo de uso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/89311/101) que não vou colocar aqui porque isso já foi respondido. [Outros exemplos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/245579/101). Coloquei um exemplo clássico, apesar de não ser exatamente assim que se usa na prática, dá um bom entendimento. E [por último](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5290/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

Vou me ater apenas a um exemplo de polimorfismo:

Todo animal emite um som, então qualquer Animal que se considere um animal tem que implementar esse método `emitirSom()`:

```
interface Animal {
    void emitirSom();
}
```

O cachorro é um animal, então ele tem o método dele:

```
class Cachorro implements Animal {

    @Override
    public void emitirSom() {
        System.out.println("Au au");
    }
}
```

E o gato também:

```
class Gato implements Animal {

    @Override
    public void emitirSom() {
        System.out.println("Miau");
    }
}
```

Temos então um método para ouvir o som de um animal. Note que é um método genérico. Ele vai receber um animal e precisa chamar o método `emitirSom()` daquele animal, seja qual for. É aqui que ocorre o polimorfismo. Em tempo de compilação, tudo o que ele sabe é que algum animal vai aparecer por ali como parâmetro.

```
static void ouvirSom(Animal animal) {
        animal.emitirSom();
}
```

Finalmente, vamos testar o método `ouvirSom()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ouvirSom(new Cachorro());
    ouvitSom(new Gato());
}
```

Imprime:

```
//Au au
//Miau
```

Novamente, perceba que o método `ouvirSom(Animal animal)` não sabia qual animal seria passado para ele em tempo de compilação, poderia ser qualquer um que estendesse Animal. Em tempo de execução, quando o parâmetro fosse passado, o polimorfismo se encarregaria de chamar o `emitirSom()` do animal utilizado, e foi o que aconteceu, imprimindo corretamente o som do animal.

Comment: Eu imagino que que ele não quer apenas um exemplo, até porque se for isto, já foi respondido antes, conforme minha resposta mostra.

Comment: @Maniero Sua resposta é bastante elucidativa, excelente, entretanto, o exemplo que você linkou, na minha opinião, é confuso para quem, como demonstra o OP, parece estar tentando começar a compreender o polimorfismo. Na verdade, tentei com o meu exemplo complementar sua excelente resposta e deixar como referência para futuras consultas de outras pessoas.

Comment: Ok, pode ser, se bem que é um exemplo real de uso, o seu é artificial e na prática não é usado, mas tudo bem, mas essa não é a questão que eu falei, é que eu acho que isto não responde o que foi perguntado, e se responder, a pergunta é duplicata. Inclusive porque tem várias formas de usar o polimorfismo, e esta não pode ser considerada a forma correta, apenas uma opção. Se ele quer entender o básico, a pergunta é duplicata. Vou por mais alguns *links*